# Yii2: Passing params to breadcrumbs

Tags: yii2, parameters, breadcrumbs

I would like to know there is a proper way of keeping track of URL params in Yii2 breadcrumbs. For instance, if I have something like:

```
Start / BrowsingLevel-1
```

corresponding to:

```
myroute/index?id=4
```

then I browse ahead to:

```
Start / BrowsingLevel-1 / BrowsingLevel-2
```

And then (using breadcrumbs) try to browse back to:

```
Start / BrowsingLevel-1
```

It ends leading me to:

```
myroute/index
```

This is not what I expected.

Comment: You can create a dummy controller with views with gii. There you can see how Breadcrumps are used as an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The breadcrumbs are whatever you have created. If they are not giving the correct results, then you need to change them. From what you are describing, it looks like in your browsingLevel-2 view file you need to change the breadcrumb links there. Yii2 does not automatically keep track of links for you, you need to set them up manually.